# hyperlink on Text in cell using phpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i)->getCell('A' . $j)
->getHyperlink('mytext')
->setUrl('http://abc.com');
```

i am trying to link a specific part of text in cell, but its linking to a whole cell, is there any solution to do it? 
OR
if i do it with multiple cells, is there any way to apply width of specific row in a sheet?
e.g.

**ROW1** CELL1 CELL2 CELL3 CELL4 
**ROW2** ----CELL1----CELL2----
**ROW3** ----CELL1----CELL2----
**ROW4** ----CELL1----CELL2----

Comment: How would you set a hyperlink only on the text and not on the cell in MS Excel itself?

Comment: is there any other solution. i have ID :3434 i want to add link on this number

Comment: I don't understand the problem.... I don't believe it's possible in MS Excel itself, so why should it be possible in PHPExcel?

Comment: I came here with the same guestion, I don't know excel that well...
@MarkBaker I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: For the multiple cells part of the question: you can merge cells with PhpWord to get the result like you have illustrated (your question wasn't exactly this, but I assumed that you might be meaning this based on the illustration).

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved by using below code.

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i)->SetCellValue(A1, 'mytext');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i)->getCell(A1)->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://abc.co');
```